# Ionic Cordova custom plugin crashing app

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, plist

I have made a custom plugin to give my app access to apple music. The issue I am facing is when the app tries to authorize on ios it should popup a dialog asking the user for permission to use apple music, but instead it crashes the app. I have added `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription` to my apps `.plist` file, but it is still not working.

Comment: please provide your source code

Comment: @sunielkalwani here is a link to the plugin I made. https://github.com/khevamann/CordovaAppleMusic